# getDate() returning the day before, but everything seems correct

Tags: javascript

I send a date back to my backend to create.

The back end recieves the end date:

```
console.log(req.params.end); // req.params.end > 2019-01-17
```

I create a date out object out of it

```
var endDate = new Date(req.params.end);
console.log(endDate); endDate > 2019-01-17T00:00:00.000Z (nice)
```

I begin to separate the year/month/date

```
var endYear = endDate.getFullYear();
var endMonth = endDate.getMonth() + 1; // 1 - 12 range
var endDay = endDate.getDate();
```

but the day is always wrong, it's one day before:

```
console.log('end date : ', endDay); // end date : 16
```

setting the time zone doesn't make a difference (I'm EST) (before I extract the date)

```
var est = { timeZone: "America/New_York" };
endDate.toLocaleString("en-US", est);
```

I also have a start date which is fairly identical  and it behaves as expected:

```
var startDate = new Date(req.params.year,tmpStartMonth,req.params.day);
console.log(startDate) // startDate > 2019-01-10T05:00:00.000Z (this is correct)

var startDay = startDate.getDate();
console.log(startDay) // startDay > 10
```

does the following time after day affect my result somehow? I'm fairly confused about what's going wrong here.

Comment: Your date is in the UTC timezone, use `getUTCDate()`

Comment: But wouldnt the change of time zone I do change it to EST there for allowing getDate to be correct?

Comment: You're not changing the time zone, you only create a string representation that considers that time zone. The date object is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happening. When you create the Date object, you get a UTC date. In your case, you get 01/17/2019 at 00.00 UTC. I imagine you are in the US, so that date would actually be 01/16 for you.

```js
var utcDate = new Date('2019-01-17T00:00:00.000Z');
console.log(utcDate);
console.log(utcDate.getDate()); // 16
```

If you instead create the date with the correct timezone for you, you will get the date that you expect. Here's an example for Pacific Time (UTC-8).

```js
var myDate = new Date('2019-01-17T00:00:00.000-08:00');
console.log(myDate);
console.log(myDate.getDate()); // 17
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong here (example taken from [mozilla `getDate()` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getDate)  maybe you have to check the entry

```js
var endDate = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30');

console.log(endDate.getFullYear());
console.log(endDate.getMonth()+1); // 1 - 12 range
console.log(endDate.getDate());
```